# dijit -- registry.byNode vs registry.getEnclosingWidget

Tags: dojo

Refer to the http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html
Both can input a Node and Return Widget?
What is the practical use of them?

Comment: In your question, you asked me to read a web page.  Ok... did that.  And then you ask "BOTH" can input a node and return widget.  Both WHAT?  I'd suggest spending more time on the question and making it clear to the readers what it is you are asking.

Comment: ok, if you don't know dijit, just skip it. I have not force you to read anything. ok?

Comment: beware when you using UPPER CASE WORDS, It is very impolite and not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`registry.byNode` just checks the given node and returns the widget that it belongs to.

`registry.getEnclosingWidget` will walk up the DOM until it finds a node that represents a widget.

This means that when given a DOM node of a widget, they will both return the same thing. [See this note in the documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html#finding-the-nearest-enclosing-widget-for-a-dom-node) about that specific case. `registry.getEnclosingWidget` is useful if you have a node that you know is associated with a certain widget but that it is not necessarily a root widget node itself.